# Github's CodeFactor complains about complexity of a simple function

Tags: c++, github

I'm trying to make a contribution to duckdb (https://github.com/cwida/duckdb). But CodeFactor complains about a seemingly innocuous C++ function.

Error given by CodeFactor: "Complex Method  (complexity = 16)". More info at: https://www.codefactor.io/repository/github/cwida/duckdb/pull/249

```
bool mod_matches_arguments(vector<SQLType> &arguments) {
    if (arguments.size() != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (arguments[0].id) {
```

Ideally I just want this error to go away with no changes to my patch.

Comment: Well if you make no changes to your patch, and it doesn't like your patch, then why would you expect it to magically go away?

Comment: You could eliminate half of that function (removing the need for the second `switch`) by writing a loop and making sure that id[i] is "good".

Comment: True. Adding a for loop eliminated the extra switch case and solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to see a way of disabling the error message by e.g. using a magic comment or a config setting. Suggestions to "improve" the code don't seem relevant to me here.

Answer (score 1):

You can amend your current PR ([`cwida/duckdb` PR 249](https://github.com/cwida/duckdb/pull/249/files)) simply by creating a new commit in your local PR branch, and pushing back to your current remote PR branch (the one from which you have opened the pull request)

That will be enough to update your *existing* PR.

And that would fix (following  PaulMcKenzie's suggestion) the [Cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) issue.

Comment: I think that this answer does not answer the question, which I believe was about disabling this particular error message in the particular place.

Comment: @Grwlf True, it was more about a workaround than actually disabling the error message.